# How to use vcl components in console applications?

Tags: console-application, c++builder, c++builder-xe

Although I have included header `vcl.h`, I get a linker error when trying to use `TStringList` objects in console application. My particular question is how to use `TStringList` and other vcl components in console applications. Here is my code snippet and the below is the linker error.

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Classes::TStringList::' referenced from XXX.OBJ

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include <tchar.h>
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>


#pragma argsused

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TStringList* AList = new TStringList;
    delete AList;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the [Console Wizard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/New_Console_Application) to create the project, make sure to enable the 'Use VCL" checkbox:

> Creates an application that can contain VCL components. This option is available only if you choose C++ as your Source Type. Checking this option causes the IDE to include vcl.h **and to change the startup code and linker options for compatibility with VCL objects**.

[image: screenshot]